# ocaml weired recursion

Tags: ocaml, caml

I am trying to calculate the square root of a number by Ocaml, this is my code :

```
let isclose x y =  abs_float(x -. y)<0.001;;
let average x y = (0.5*.x)+.(0.5*.y);;
let rec guess x y = if isclose y (x /. y) then y else guess x (average y x/.y);;
let sqr x = guess x 1.;;
```

then, typing

```
sqr 1.;;
```

gives 1 as expected, but typing

```
sqr 2.;;
```

lasts undefinitely.
Can one help with my error (I tested the algo in Python and it works as expected).
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
let rec guess x y =
    if isclose y (x /. y) then y else guess x (average y (x/.y))
```

Note the extra parentheses.

The meaning of

```
average y x /. y
```

is

```
(average y x) /. y
```

Whereas you want:

```
average y (x /. y)
```